# Mobile browser support for SQL Server CE?

Tags: mobile, sql-server-ce

which browsers support SQL Server CE on mobile platforms? Does SQL Server CE come preinstalled (like SQLite) or user have to download it separately?

Comment: I've never had SQLite preinstalled on any of my mobile devices...

Comment: WebKit based browsers (firefox) comes with SQLLite installed as part of browser package, afaik

Comment: The only mobile platform I'm aware of that supports Firefox is Android. If you're asking about SQL CE on a mobile platform, that does limit you to Windows CE / Windows Mobile / Windows Phone, and at that level not the browsers, but in applications you'd write; But by referring to browsers implies that you're interested in HTML5's web database, rather than specific SQL engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, none, though I don't exactly have encyclopedic knowledge of mobile browser capabilities.

SQL CE would be embedded in your application, so in theory there would be nothing for the user to install. If you're developing a mobile web application, then SQL CE would be embedded within your web app on the server. If you're looking for a client-side solution, then SQL CE is probably not the right choice.